# show up Linux partition on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, file-sharing, share, shared-folders

I have 5 systems that are connected to a network switch

```
Desktop(1) : Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Netbook(1) : Windows 7 Starter

Desktop(1) : Windows 7 Professional

Laptops(2) : Ubuntu 11.04
```

Now, I need to make a data-backup central, which store all data (from all my systems) on Desktop running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

What I need is, how to make my Linux system show up on Windows?

I also want to map user-to-directory, so that when I log-in to my desktop using Windows, I should be asked Login Credentials, and on successful login, I should be presented on that directory, that I have permission.

Comment: For windows permissions you might be better served on [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: We have more that one question here.
Focus on single tasks:
"How can I backup my personal computers using linux"?
"How can I automatically mount personal shares on a samba server using linux after logging in?"

And so on :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to share a folder from linux to windows you need to use Samba.

The quickest way of achieving this is to right click on the folder select 'Properties > Share > "Share this Folder"' and Ubuntu should install the relevant files needed.

Comment: this will only work from one machine to the other and not for the partitions on the same machine

Comment: @Dirk Hartzer Waldeck You comment is a bit misleading, let me clarify: Samba is like Windows shares, so Samba can't work if Ubuntu is powered off. If you want to access a Linux partition from Windows (on the same PC), you can only do it if said partition format is recognized by Windows like NTFS. But since I-M-JM seems to be looking for a networked solution, Samba should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Samba to share the folder in ubuntu, you can set permisions for users with samba, map each drive on the windows boxes

Looking here for help on user and perms.
[Samba](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/)

As for login credentials unless you plan on adding an Active Directory you will have to have them locally set on the machine.  You can use a windows login script to automatically open the direcorory on login.